# Error: Argument of type 'typeof ModernCharts' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string

Tags: spfx

Cloned Modern Charts 
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-modern-charts

Added webpart src folder to my existing working project.
Ran `gulp serve` and received error:

> Argument of type 'typeof ModernCharts' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ComponentClass | StatelessComponent'.
>   Type 'typeof ModernCharts' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent'.
>   Type 'typeof ModernCharts' provides no match for the signature '(props: IModernChartsProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement'.

Didn't make any changes to the original code except updated the config.json and package.json to reflect the lines of the modern chart.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add all necessary npm packages to ``package.json`` and run ``npm install``?

Comment: I did. I added all the different package reference from their package.json into mine. Of course, ran "npm install" again.

Comment: This issue is still there, I also have the same problem. I found this: [Argument of type 'typeof ModernCharts'](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/429). But I still have problems with the `const chartArea` part, If you find the answer, please let me know